# Basic Ajax POST sending values arrives null in the controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I know this is a question that is regularly asked everywhere on the forums of dev but despite having searched I can not find what stuck.

I'm just trying to pass some values through an Ajax POST to my controller.
Ajax receives the values but they arrive null in my controller.

I tried declaring a model that has the same variable names and I also tried putting each field in the signature of my method (with the same variable names) but the result is always the same: null.

Is it possible that this does not work because the model of my view is different from the model with which I want to receive my data?

Would you have an idea of what is stuck and especially what is it due?

Thx!

**Controller V1**

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> ShowRegistration(Models.RegisterForm rF)
{
```

**Controller V2**

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ShowRegistration(string Id, string Status, string Checkin, string Checkout, string Cost, bool Terms, bool Info, string Member_Zkp)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

**Model**

```
public class RegisterForm
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Checkin { get; set; }
    public string Checkout { get; set; }
    public string Cost { get; set; }
    public bool Terms { get; set; }
    public int TermsINT { get; set; }
    public int InfoINT { get; set; }
    public bool Info { get; set; }
    public string Member_Zkp { get; set; }
}
```

**Ajax Function**

```
function Edit() {

    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $('#Zkp').val();
    var status = $('#StatusDrop').val();
    var cost = $('#Cost').val();
    var checkin = $('#Checkin').val();
    var checkout = $('#Checkout').val();
    var check1 = $('#check1').val();
    var check2 = $('#check2').val();
    var dataRegister = { "Id": id, "Status": status, "Cost": cost, "Terms": check1, "Info": check2 };

    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
    $('#alertWait').show('fade');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#alertWait').hide('fade');
    }, 4000);

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://localhost:44338/Registration/ShowRegistration/",
        data: { "Id" : id, "Status": status, "Cost": cost, "Terms": check1, "Info": check2 },
        type: 'POST',

        contentType: 'application/JSON',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data === "success") {
                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
                $('#alertOk').show('fade');

                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#alertOk').hide('fade');
                }, 4000);
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
            $('#alertError').show('fade');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#alertError').hide('fade');
            }, 4000);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: are you authorised when you do your post?

Comment: Yep, i'm logged in and i enter in the method but all of my values are null.

Comment: try to remove double quotes from every key in your post data like => `data: { Id : id, Status: status, Cost: cost, Terms: check1, Info: check2 }`

Comment: or you could use `data: $('#formid').serialize()`

Comment: @Pete Yep but it isnt a form. The model in my view contains a list<Events> and a list<SubEvents>, i use 2 foreach, one for Events and one for SubEvents (maybe i could still use a form like this, im not an expert).

Comment: @Korpin, did u tried with removing double quotes?

Comment: @er-shoaib Yep i just did and my values are still null :(

Comment: @er-shoaib i did my test only with: ShowRegistration(string Id, string Status, string Cost) AND i the view: data: { Id : id, Status: status, Cost: cost },

Comment: Ah right I always make sure my data can post without js enabled for added accessibility and security, therefore I always have my inputs wrapped in a form.  Are you sure the ajax is being hit and there are no errors in your console?  just noticed you have a prevent default at the top but don't pass the event into the function

Comment: try to hide this line => `contentType: 'application/JSON',` your ajax call work my side except this line

Comment: @er-shoaib --> It works now! Well the string are working but no the bool and the date :p Thanks for your help already!!

Comment: Yep offcourse i was just going to ask you for it! May i also ask you how could i pass the date? I always receive the 01/01/01. For checkboxes i found how to get the value with .is(':checked');

Comment: Did you try changing your url ? `url: "Registration/ShowRegistration/",`

Comment: @Korpin, how you pass the date to server by using input field textbox or any jquery datepicker?

Comment: Ok it works, mybad i forgot to add my dates in the data :-)

Comment: @Korpin, I added my answer below, mark it and vote up by clicking up arrow :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all

Try to remove double quotes from every key in your post data like.

```
data: { Id : id, Status: status, Cost: cost, Terms: check1, Info: check2 }
```

And then,

Try to hide this line from your ajax call.

```
contentType: 'application/JSON',
```

Answer (score 0):

Serialize your object to json before sending it :

```
data: JSON.stringify({ "Id": id, "Status": status, "Cost": cost, "Terms": check1, "Info": check2 }),
```

you can also receive the model, instead of declaring x variables

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(RegisterForm model)
```

Comment: I had already tried to use JSON.stringify but my values are still null =/ (i just did it again with your code)

Comment: I copy your code to my projecte, Open chrome console and had an “Invalid JSON primitive” error, change that 2 lines and all worked ok. I could get id value etc etc

Comment: @Korpin basic question, but $('#Zkp').val(); is returning a value?

Comment: @IvanValadares debug on chrome to see you get all values there, and then,start with only one parameter to check , then eventually increase paramterrs